# Could not update containr args in Pods - kuberneties -got 'pod updates may not change fields'

Tags: javascript, kubernetes, kubectl

I am trying to update entrypoint in specific container

the struture is :
statefulset -> list of pods -> specificPod -> specific contianer

I tried to do that using the javascript client and got the following:

```
    body: {
      kind: 'Status',
      apiVersion: 'v1',
      metadata: {},
      status: 'Failure',
      message: 'Pod "name-0" is invalid: spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than `spec.containers[*].image`, `spec.initContainers[*].image`, `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` or `spec.tolerations` (only additions to existing tolerations)\n' +
        '  core.PodSpec{\n' +
```

I did the following:

```
  for(let c of pod.spec.containers){
        if(c.name === 'name'){
            console.log('in name contianer');
            c.args = ['test;sleep 3600'];
        }
    }
    
await coreV1Api.replaceNamespacedPod(podName,namespace, pod);
```

this is works if I will update the stateful set args but I need only for specific pod

is it possible?

Comment: I am no kubernetes expert (have started for a month of 2) but i believe the message is clear. You cannot change the args of a specific pod (might be possible only to change statefulset args)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. The whole point of using a `StatefulSet` is to have a bunch of `Pods` that are basically identical. It is the precise goal of the `Controller Manager` to reconcile the `StatefulSet` resource and ensure there are `replicas` number of `Pods` that match the `StatefulSet` spec.

If you want to have different pods you need to have different StatefulSets.